# Excel 2013 Formula to validate binary data and exclude blank cells (would also love help simplifying current formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have people inputting data for 16 questions marking respondents' `Yeses` with **1** and `Nos` with **0**, but in the past I have had trouble with silly errors either with **blanks** or with **other numbers**, so I am adding another column to verify that each of the 16 cells have either a **0** or a **1**.

I figured out a long formula with *16 OR* functions nested in an *AND* function, (so if someone has a more elegant approach, that'd be great also) but if there are cells left blank, my formula counts them as a 0. Any ideas?

```
=IF(AND(OR(A3=1;A3=0);OR(B3=1;B3=0); [...];)=TRUE;0;1)
```

The If function that it is all nested is so that I can sum the thousand or so rows in conditional formatting and turn the header red if the sum does not equal 0:

Format values where this formula is true: =SUM($Q:$Q)<>0

Answer (score 2):

To test if all the cells in **A1** through **P1** ae either ***1*** or ***0***, use:

```
=AND(COUNTBLANK(A1:P1)=0,COUNTIF(A1:P1,1)+COUNTIF(A1:P1,0)=16)
```

the first part catches bad blanks, he second part catches bad numbers

Comment: Nice answer. Is the COUNTBLANK part necessary?

Comment: @davidmneedham probably not since *COUNTIF(whatever,0)* does not treat blank as 0

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much! I ended up nesting what you provided (minus the COUNTBLANK per @Gary'sStudent advice) in an if statement so that True=0, False=1, then conditional formatting on the header can sum the column and turn the cell red if the sum does not equal 0.

Thanks again everyone!